error: Automation error. The system cannot find the file specified in vb6
I have an application in VB6 and need to create an object of a class that is part of another .dll (written in VB.NET). Now I am using the CreateObject() method (I am following the same logic used in other parts of the application) but it is giving me this error:

Automation error. The system cannot find the file specified.

Since VB6 is quite old I have not worked a lot with it and don't understand why my .dll is not working but works for others. Am I missing any step?
Public Function DoRun() As Object
    Set DoRun = CreateObject("U_DoRun.ClassName",SERVERNAME)
End Function

I have tried to use this command:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.\regasm.exe c:\windows\syswow64\U_DoRun.dll /codebase /tlb:c:\windows\syswow64\U_DoRun.tlb

After I do this if I try to give a value to a variable of the class it gives another error:

Could not load file or assembly 'DLLNAME.dll, Version= or one of its dependencies. The specified file could not be found.

and also the object of the class seems to be empty (It says 'No variables') which makes me think that it does not create the object correctly. What can I do to solve this?

Did you actually put your assembly to windows\syswow64? Why?

@GSerg Yeah I did put it there before running the command. I saw a comment in another post that said to try this. After doing that I am able to create the object without any Automation error but the object is empty..

CreateObject ask for a COM Server (here it's an in-process server, U_DoRun.dll). You don't need to put a COM dll in the Windows directory since you register it it can be anymore (accessible in terms of security to the client) but more important it seems like your U_DoRun.dll also needs some NetArch assembly around. You should put U_DoRun.dll and all dependencies (like NetArch etc.) into a folder and call regasm from that folder. COM will then locate it. Note: if you really use a SERVERNAME (ie: DCOM), then it's more complicated.

@SimonMourier do you perhaps know what NetArch is? I don't know where to find it

I've no idea but it's clearly needed. Look for some NetArch.dll somewere

And just to make sure: you're .NET DLL is compiled to be COM visible, right?
